# Big cheese meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does "big cheese" mean a celebrity or an important person?

I think there is a difference between celebrity and an important person.

And can I use big cheese in a context that denotes I'm referring to a celebrity?

Can I use it like this?

> "Will Smith is a big cheese."

Comment: It's the same as the head honcho.  Except to a mouse.

Comment: Hello, David. You can search Google for definitions by adding "define" in front of a word. For example, search for _"define big cheese"_.

Comment: This site has a helpful picture of a big cheese: http://www.idioms4you.com/complete-idioms/big-cheese.html

Comment: @NVZ I already did that I'm just confused as I explained in the question

Comment: It doesn't normally apply to celebrities. See my above link: "the most important or influential person, ***usually in an organization, business or government***."

Comment: @David Powell, but see the comments to NVZ's answer. If you add "in Hollywood" or "in the film industry", then you can use it. "Will Smith is a big cheese ***in Hollywood***."

Comment: Of related interest: [Why does "big cheese" mean someone important?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78166/why-does-big-cheese-mean-someone-important)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Big cheese** — [Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/big-cheese)

> *noun, Older Slang.* 1. an influential or important person
>   *"Who's the big cheese around here?"*

A big cheese — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+big+cheese)

> *humorous* an important or powerful person in a group or organization.
>   *"Apparently her father is a big cheese in one of the major banks."*

It doesn't sound okay when you say *"Will Smith is a big cheese."* Instead, you should mention a group or organisation. For example, this is much better.

> "Will Smith is a big cheese in the film industry"

Comment: can I use it like this " Will Smith is a big cheese. " ?

Comment: No, I would say more like: "Will Smith is a big cheese in Hollywood."

Comment: FWIW I would use big cheese in more specific circumstances rather than just to denote a persons general popularity -  e.g. "Will Smith is a big cheese at the Screen Actors Guild of Naff Movies", "Donald trump is the big cheese at Trump Intl.", etc

Comment: @DavidPowell No, I don't think that sounds okay. But try instead, "Will Smith is a big cheese in the film industry".